# Не проходит авторизация

Tags: сессия, php, авторизация

Доброе вроемя суток. Пытаюсь реализовать регистрацию и авторизацию пользователей на сайте. Регистрация работает нормально, однако авторизация нет... Собственно вот код. Проблема даже не в том... Авторизация можно сказать проходит на половину, в сессию переменные не записываются, а перенаправление (в конце кода) происходит. Прошу помощи. Заранее спасибо.

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; if ($login == '') { unset($login);} } //заносим введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
if (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }
//заносим введенный пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
if (empty($login) or empty($password)) //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
{
exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
}
//если логин и пароль введены,то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести
$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);
//удаляем лишние пробелы
$login = trim($login);
$password = trim($password);
 // подключаемся к базе
        include ("connect.php");
// минипроверка на подбор паролей
        $ip=getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
        if (empty($ip) || $ip=='unknown') {    $ip=getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"); }//извлекаем ip           
mysql_query ("DELETE FROM oshibka WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() -    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 900");//удаляем ip-адреса ошибавшихся при входе пользователей через 15 минут.           
$result = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE    ip='$ip'",$db);// извлекаем из базы количество неудачных попыток входа за    последние 15 у пользователя с данным ip 
        $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 if ($myrow['col'] > 4) {
        //если ошибок больше двух, т.е три, то выдаем сообщение.
        exit("Вы набрали логин или пароль неверно 5 раз. Подождите 15 минут до следующей попытки.");
        }

    $password    = md5(md5($password));//шифруем пароль
        $password    = strrev($password);// для надежности добавим реверс
        $password    = $password."11fff";

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND pass='$password'",$db); //извлекаем из базы все данные о пользователе с введенным логином и паролем
        $myrow    = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if (empty($myrow['id']))
        {
        //если пользователя с введенным логином и паролем не существует
        //Делаем запись о том, что данный ip не смог войти.
        $select = mysql_query ("SELECT ip FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'");
        $tmp = mysql_fetch_row ($select);
        if ($ip == $tmp[0]) {//проверяем, есть ли пользователь в таблице "oshibka" 
        $result52 = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'",$db);
        $myrow52 = mysql_fetch_array($result52);          
        $col = $myrow52[0] + 1;//прибавляем    еще одну попытку неудачного входа 
        mysql_query ("UPDATE oshibka SET col=$col,date=NOW() WHERE ip='$ip'");
        }          
        else {
        mysql_query ("INSERT INTO oshibka (ip,date,col) VALUES    ('$ip',NOW(),'1')");
        //если за последние 15 минут ошибок не было, то вставляем новую запись в таблицу "oshibka"
        }

        exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин или пароль неверный.");
        }
        else {
    //если пароли совпадают, то запускаем пользователю сессию! Можете его поздравить, он вошел!
            $_SESSION['password']=$myrow['pass']; 
            $_SESSION['login']=$myrow['login']; 
            $_SESSION['id']=$myrow['id']; //эти данные очень часто используются, вот их и будет "носить с собой" вошедший пользователь
            }                  
        echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=../profile/index.php'></head></html>";//перенаправляем пользователя на главную страничку, там    ему и сообщим об удачном входе

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Голимый код. 1999 года производства.

Инициализация переменных login и password замысловатая. Вот так намного проще:

```
<?php
$login = !empty($_POST['login']) ? $_POST['login'] : false;
$password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;
$login = trim(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($login)));
// а вот над $password таким образом издеваться не рекомендуется, потому что для безопасности в пароле должны быть разрешены все символы и вообще пароль пропускается через md5
//...
if (empty($login) || empty($password)) {
    // ... не указан логин/пароль
}
?>
```

куча exit.

password порадовал ;) ну, да - подобрать не удастся. Вот такой код намного компактнее и тоже подобрать не удастся ([читать про это](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)):

```
$salt = "случайная строка, например из файлика config.php". $password = md5($salt . $password);
```

для трёх запросов `SELECT ip FROM oshibka`, `UPDATE oshibka` и `INSERT INTO oshibka` есть один запрос [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Сохранять даже зашифрованный пароль `$_SESSION['password']` в сессию небезопасно. У тебя там уже есть id пользователя.

Перед тем, как работать с сессией, её надо стартовать. `session_start()` перед `$_SESSION`

Вместо ответа HTTP 200 с meta-refresh нужно сразу [перенаправлять на другую страницу](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)

Comment: Подскажите тогда пожалуйста где найти мануал как написать правильно)

Comment: посмотри мои контакты

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0;
   URL=../profile/index.php'></head></html>";
```

Используйте редирект

```
header("Location: http://mydomain.com//profile/index.php");
```

Самое главное:
session_start() - вы вызвали эту функцию перед тем как создать сессию?

Comment: в `login.php` (страница с формой) - `session_start()` вызван,
а если в обработчике (представленный код) вызвать в начале `session_start()`, тогда происходит редирект на главную, но там: 

http://prntscr.com/3mzmiq

на строке 2:
    session_start();

на строке 11:
    $myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);